# Is there a limit to the number of Spot rates than can be calculated from Par Yields

Tags: fixed-income, programming, bond, spot-rate

I am just trying to calculate Spot Rates from Par yields. I find that the code below gives very similar spot rates for the data [here](http://financialexamhelp123.com/par-curve-spot-curve-and-forward-curve/), yet if I increase the size of the `yields` array I end up getting NaN values from the Python code as `adding_negatives` turns out to be greater than `face_values[index]` making `term_1` negative. I've basically just directly implemented the steps in the link to get the Spot Rates.

```
#df is a Dataframe that contains the bond information
import numpy as np
face_values = df['FACE_VALUE'].values #ALL 100 as only Par Bonds are taken
yields = (df['coupon'].values) #PAR YIELDS         
spot_rate = np.zeros((yields.shape[0]))    

#Obtaining Spot Yields
for x, coupon in np.ndenumerate(yields):
    index = x[0]
    if index == 0:
        spot_rate[index] = (yields[index]/face_values[index]) * 100
    else:    
        adding_negatives = 0
        if index < spot_rate.shape[0]:
            for i in range (0, index, 1):
                adding_negatives = adding_negatives + (coupon/2)/np.power((1+(spot_rate[i]/200)),i+1)                        
            term_1 = face_values[index] - adding_negatives 
            spot_rate[index] = 2*(((np.power(((((face_values[index] + ((coupon/2)))/term_1))),1/(index+1)))-1)) * 100
```

If `yields` is a Vector like this:

`[ 1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5
  1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.5    1.75   2.
  2.     2.     2.05   2.1    2.5    2.99   4.     4.04   4.1    4.5    4.8
  4.875  4.97   5.125  5.25   5.5    5.75   5.75   5.95   5.967  6.15   6.3
  6.375]`, some of the Spot Rates turn out to be NaN as `adding_negative` keeps adding up and turns to be greater than 100 (`face_values[index]`)  eventually.

Please let me know if more information is required. *This code is directly usable, with the `yields` array given above.*

**Edit**: In reference to Gordon's comment:

To get the spot rate for the 2'nd period:

$$\text{Price} = \frac{c/2}{1 + spotrate_{period 0}/200} +  \frac{facevalue + c/2}{(1 + spotrate_{period 1}/200)^2} $$

The code basically follows the steps:

$$\text{adding_negatives} = \frac{c/2}{1 + spotrate_{period 0}/200}$$

$$\text{term_1} = \text{Price} - \text{adding_negatives}$$

$$spotrate_{period 1} = 2 * ((((\text{facevalue} + (\text{coupon/2}))/\text{term_1})^{1/periodno} -1))$$

Also, with regards to the spot rates in the Link:

The code gives: `[ 2.      2.4024  2.7669  3.0933  3.4021  3.6721]`

The link gives: `[ 2.      2.4024  2.7669  3.0974  3.3975  3.6701]`, so maybe there actually is an Error here too?

Thank You

Comment: If you can write out specifically the relationship between the spot rate and the yield in a formulaic form, it will be more helpful to isolate the problem.

Comment: @Gordon I've added the formulaic form of the code. I hope it is clearer as to the way I am thinking about it now.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have the definition for par yield as well?

Comment: @Gordon I'm taking Par Yields to be the Coupons of those bonds which are priced at Par. So, in the code above I just choose bonds which have a price of 100.

Comment: Then you basically want to solve an equation to obtain the spot rate.

Comment: @Gordon Yeah. So, I am trying to solve the above equations to get the spot rate from the par yields. Conceptually it seems to make sense, so that's why I think the code may be wrong or at least the steps I am taking in those equations are incorrect.

Comment: @Gordon Or maybe even the data I am using may not be correct. I just want to narrow down on which of these may be the issue. Thank You.

Comment: I do not find the problem. The data may be wrong.

Comment: @Gordon Thank you very much for your help. I guess that's a whole different issue in itself.

Comment: @Gordon And finally, do you think that the code giving spot rates of `[ 2.      2.4024  2.7669  3.0933  3.4021  3.6721]`, whilst the link gives `[ 2.      2.4024  2.7669  3.0974  3.3975  3.6701]`, for the same set of par yields, could be an issue? I rounded the numbers to 4 decimal places, but still they're slightly off.

Comment: I do not see this a big problem. But, for confirmation, you might manually check this using Excel.